# Rename Ethernet Adapter In Docker windowsservercore Image

Tags: windows, docker, network-programming, windows-10

I'm running a `microsoft/windowsservercore` container on Windows 10 and trying to rename the network adapter from within the container by any means possible.  This would be a simple task via PowerShell with something like the following:

`Rename-NetAdapter -Name 'Ethernet 2' -NewName 'WuTangLan'`

but that gives the following error:

`Rename-NetAdapter : A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.
At line:1 char:1
+ Rename-NetAdapter -Name 'Ethernet 2' -NewName 'WuTangLan'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_NetAdapter..."3e77a8955741"):ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetAdapter) [
   Rename-NetAdapter], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800106d9,Rename-NetAdapter`

Is there any way to rename the network adapter from within the container?

Comment: I'm curious, what's the use case for that?

Comment: I'm running software that expects an interface of a specific name.